# Dynamically creating 1 or more lists in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, loops

I am trying to build a method that dynamically creates lists or arrays based on the number of strings in an array. The names must be Group1, Group2, Group3, etc.
I am sure a foreach loop and reflection could accomplish this, but I'm not sure how. I have never used reflection before.
Possible psuedocode:

```
foreach(string token in array)
{
   CreateList("Group" + number);
}
```

Then there's the issue of defining that number.

Comment: Are you trying to create a visual array? Or are you simply looking for a means to create N Lists for N Strings? A bit of background can help on this.

Comment: N Lists for N strings in array, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I understand your question, hope this code helps. I am assuming that you are going to save string in the created list/array, thus `List<string>`

```
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dc = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            int count = 0;

            foreach (string group in array)
            {
                dc.Add("Group" + (++count), new List<string>());
            }

            //you can later retrieve the list from dictionary
            if (dc.ContainsKey("Group1"))
            {
                List<string> list = dc["Group1"];
                //and you can then use the list
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary` could be handy; where the key to dictionary is "Group" + number.